# Open source FEM implementation for Windows

Tags: finite-element, computational-physics, open-source

I am wondering is there any robust, well-tested, accurate open source FEM solver package for Windows? I would like to use to power the engine of my structural engineering application.

The FEM package should come with

1. Meshing algorithm
2. Static solver
3. Modal Analysis
4. Everything that is standard for structural engineering application

I don't need it to run on clusters, because my application should be able to run on personal laptops.

I took a look at [Code_Aster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_Aster), but it is not supported natively on Windows.

I can find [a list of such packages at wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_finite_element_software_packages), but I am not sure which one is alive and under development, and which one is a dead-end project.

Comment: Why does it have to be natively supported in Windows? Use cygwin

Comment: @Kbzon, I can't ask my client to get themselves a Cygwin-- they are not technical enough for that.

Comment: Metafor maybe  ?

Comment: @Blue_Elephant, [Metafor](http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php) is a statistical software package, not FEM

Comment: What do you mean by "solver?" One reason I ask is that the traditional usage of "solver" in this context does not include meshing. What is the source of the geometry you require the mesher to mesh (e.g. CAD system)? Is a capability for geometry creation required? Do you need both 2D and 3D geometry? Beam elements? Shell elements? I have no idea what you mean by "use to power the engine...". Your item 4 is so vague it could be construed to eliminate *all* open source software compared with commercial packages. I suggest being much more specific or removing that item.

Comment: @BillGreene , I don't need mesher( though that is welcomed). Yes, I need the beam and shell. You can look at code Asher to see what I mean

Answer (score 1):

The are [Windows ports](https://sourceforge.net/projects/asterwin/) of the open source FEM code [Code_Aster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_Aster), although these ports are not up to date with the main project, which is available on Linux or FreeBSD.

Code_Aster is part of the [Salome](http://www.salome-platform.org/) software collection, see also [Wikipedia an Salome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salome_(software)).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest OpenSees: http://opensees.berkeley.edu/index.php. Some colleagues in my department made fairly good use of it a couple of years ago in combination with SAP2000.

Comment: This is earthquake specific, but not FEM specific

Comment: FEM stands for Finite Element Method, which is a numerical method for solving Partial Differential Equations.

Comment: Generally, they also include the solution of the Differential Algebraic Equations (constraints) and not so often in the case of Structural Engineering, the Ordinary Differential Equations (time) as buildings are considered to be fairly static in time and other workarounds can be made.

Comment: OpenSees includes methods to solve all three types of differential equations above and also provides some other tools specific for helping engineers with earthquake problems.

Comment: According to the points enumerated in the question, OpenSees complies with all of them and is a well tested piece of software.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, you said your colleagues are using OpenSees in conjunction with SAP2000. I thought OpenSees can replicate most of the core SAP2000 functions? What do you need SAP2000 for?

Answer (score 1):

You may do well checking out ElmerFEM (https://csc.fi/web/elmer/elmer) - it is open-source, fairly powerful and well documented. Both Windows and Linux binaries are available.

Answer (score 1):

The followings links will help you to find out more.

1. [deal II](http://www.dealii.org/) is a nice advanced open source FEM code. See their page for more information. It also has the support for windows.
2. Also, [this link](https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_is_the_best_open_source_finite_element_software_for_mechanical_problems) provides some experience of other experts in this field.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe FreeFem would be your best choice ;) [website](http://www.freefem.org/)

Comment: Could you expand on that a bit? (This answer is so brief, it triggered the automatic "low quality post" flag.) How does FreeFem++ address the points listed in the OP? Can you download a precompiled binary for Windows? What are the prerequisites? Is it actually open source instead of just free-as-in-beer? If so, which license?